# I need help with this very hard riddle

Tags: cipher

I would appreciate anyone solving it because I have been wondering what the answer could be! Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: why did you delete and then repost this?

Comment: To replace the tag riddle with cipher ! Why is everyone asking weird questions here i stead of answering the question ?

Comment: you don't have to delete the post and repost it to change the tag. You can click 'edit' to change things in the post. And you can't expect us to just 'answer the question'. Its a low quality post and frankly I have no idea.

Comment: @Trevor Comments are often used for gather some clarification of the question if there is confusion. Like how I wanted to know if this came from somewhere. Gerbil was only informing you of the tools at your disposal such as editing a question, rather than deleting and asking again.

Comment: The comment section here is for comments such as this. If I had the answer, I'd click 'post answer' at the bottom of the page

Comment: Okay sorry I'm new here!

Comment: No worries, everyone starts somewhere. We just want to make sure you post puzzles that are complete to avoid them attracting a lot of down votes and being potentially closed. The more information the better is usually a good idea when posting puzzles that you don't know the answer to necessarily, because it makes it hard for others to figure out if there's no way to confirm anything.

Comment: The previous version of this you posted had a question number (12) and a number of points (1000). I'll take your word for it that, as you said there, this isn't from any sort of formal competition but only some kind of challenge between friends; but is there any sort of context that might make it more apparent what is going on in this question? What sort of things were in the earlier questions, for instance?

Comment: It actually is a form of challenge between friends. The numbers 12 and 1000 appeared because we just picked the riddles from an old rally paper one of us participated in a year ago. I edited the picture so people do not get confused and maybe think the numbers 12 and 1000 are part of the question. Each question is individual so previous questions have nothing to do with this one and are totally different.

Comment: looks more like a rebus

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

It looks like a set of commas separated by apostrophes, so by counting the commas between each apostrophe you get the sequence:

> 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5, 13, 3, 35, 55 (I think, counting the last two sets of commas was tricky).

At this point I'm not sure whether the goal is to get the next number in the sequence or if the numbers somehow correspond to letters and the answer is a word or phrase or what.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer

> If we consider every position as informational (instead of as information broken up by apostrophes), it works very well as binary information since there are only 2 states.

That would be

> 000111010001010001000001000001....etc

Comment: I thought about that, but I went with the idea of apostrophes as spacers rather than actual information because except for the beginning where there are three in a row, you never see more than one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Possible other answer:

> This is your activity on Tinder. With a comma being Match and an apostrophe being Not Match, At first you are appreciative of the novelty of the app and Match the first 3 you see. Then you get a little pickier, Discarding the next 3. But you dial it back because you don't want to be too selective and reject someone "good enough for tonight." As the night wears on, you have some drinks, your desperation increases, and other than your boss and your ex, you reject no other candidates. The last apostrophe is when you gave up and went to bed.

This might be a little easier with some context, I think.